# How to write a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My database has a simple table, with two columns, BID and Value. There may be some records in the database with same BID, like this:

**BID Value**

```
Record1: BID = 1, Value = 0

Record2: BID = 1, Value = 3

Record3: BID = 2, Value = 4

Record4: BID = 2, Value = 5

Record5: BID = 2, Value = 6

Record6: BID = 3, Value = 7
```

Now I want to write a SQL query that can get the total count of the BID that has more than one corresponding records.

In the above sample, BID 1 has 2 corresponding records, and BID 2 has 3. So the total count of BID values that has more than one corresponding records is 2.

How to write such a SQL query?

Comment: You listed already one keyword with `COUNT()`. The others you should look for, are `HAVING` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server here? I think one of the answers is product specific... It's a good idea to not tag products not used!

Comment: i just tested mine against mysql & sql server, works on both, so safe there

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an aggregation query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM (
    SELECT BID, COUNT(*) cnt
      FROM your_table
      GROUP BY BID
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) q
```

The inner query here groups your bids together, counts how many in each group, and then selects only those groups with more than 1 value.

The outer query simply counts the results of that query.

You can see how it works here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c9e6/3

Comment: And you don't even need to select count(*) in the sub-query, it will still work.

Comment: true that, it's there to show how the inner query works more than anything

Comment: Thank you, what is the usage of the last "q"?

Comment: It names the result of the subquery.  The derived table

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (bid int,val int)
insert into @t (bid,val)values (1,0),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,7)

;with cte as (
select bid,
       val,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY bid order by val )RN from @t
)
select  COUNT( DISTINCT bid) from cte 
where RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you need only 2 `count` one for checking the count of values for each id and the other for all ids who has more than one value, you don't need to use `having`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT BID, COUNT(*) CNT
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY BID
 ) q
 WHERE CNT>1
```

Comment: i don't think even mysql is stupid enough not to realise that the count(*) in the select is identical to the count(*) in the having, and only evaulate it once. in fact, the execution plan for this query and my version are identical